# Next.js 13 - Can't resolve 'supports-color'

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

I'm currently developing a Next.js 13 app (with TypeScript). I'm the Sendgrid npm package too.

I constantly get this warning:

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'supports-color' in '.../node_modules/debug/src'`

Running:
`npm install supports-color`
`npm install debug@latest` does not fix it, it just give this error instead:

```
Module not found: ESM packages (supports-color) need to be imported. Use 'import' to reference the package instead
```

I'm using `import` everywhere. **I have narrowed it down** to happening when I use the `Sendgrid` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/mail) but I have no clue why Sendgrid causes this error.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

There is an open issue on debug's GitHub that details more of the problem [here](https://github.com/debug-js/debug/issues/912). Installing `"supports-color": "^8.1.1"` as a work around solved the error for me.

```
npm i supports-color@8.1.1
```

Answer (score -1):

yeah i also experienced the same thing but on socket.io and socket.1o-client npm package in nextjs, the problem was solved when i installed this version

```
npm i supports-color@8.1.1
```